# Get multipart/form data in request Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am submitting form using [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin for saving images this is client Js snippet:

```
$('#saveProfileImage').ajaxForm(options);

$('#saveProfileImage').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cropBoxData = $image.cropper('getData');
    $('#image-height').val(cropBoxData.height);
    $('#image-width').val(cropBoxData.width);
    $('#image-x').val(cropBoxData.x);
    $('#image-y').val(cropBoxData.y);
    alert("Submittin");
})
```

And saving image file with [blueimp-file-upload-expressjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs) Server side code:

```
router.post('/updateprofilemedia/v1', function(request, response, next){
    console.log("Enter in updateprofilev1");
    console.log(request.data);//why i am getting empty here
    console.log(request.files)// getting undefined
    var options = {
        tmpDir: __dirname + '/../public/user_images',
        uploadDir: __dirname + '/../public/user_images',
        uploadUrl: '/uploaded/files/',
        copyImgAsThumb : false,
        storage: {
          type: 'local'
        }
      };
    var uploader = require('blueimp-file-upload-expressjs')(options);
    uploader.post(request, response, function(error, obj) {
        console.log("")
    });
});
```

Everything is fine image is saving perfectly. But i am sending extra data with request but i am getting empty here at `request.data`. and solution???

When i have used [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty) middleware i got following `request.files`, but now Uploading module not uploading image.

```
{ proflie_image: 
   { fieldName: 'proflie_image',
     originalFilename: 'profile.jpg',
     path: '/tmp/3959-hjf57u.jpg',
     headers: 
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="proflie_image"; filename="profile.jpg"',
        'content-type': 'image/jpeg' },
     ws: 
      { _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        path: '/tmp/3959-hjf57u.jpg',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 92450,
        closed: true },
     size: 92450,
     name: 'profile.jpg',
     type: 'image/jpeg' } }
```

This is following view i can see in my console:
[image]

Comment: What middleware are you using?

Comment: @BidhanA is it very necessary to use middleware? Files are saving perfectly without using any. For data do i have to use any?

Comment: Yes you need to use a middleware like bodyparser to parse the request.

Comment: Update question for more clarity

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution, may be you can want to look this. Multiparty is a module that help access both image and text fields when form arttribute is enctype="multipart/form-data".it is very useful. When you didnt specify enctype, its default is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. But it is hardfull for controll images. So if we want to send image ,we use  "multipart/form-data" .

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');

 var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if(err){ 
            throw err; 
        }else{
          console.log(fields.productType+" "+fields.imgOrder+" "+fields.productİd);
            //files iare images
            //fields are fields, you can access now to them
            // it save image in temporary file
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware. Example:

```
var multer = require('multer');

// ...

router.post('/updateprofilemedia/v1',
            multer({ dest: __dirname + '/../public/user_images' }),
            function(request, response, next) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Why to use this middleware any specific reason? It can solve my problem?

Comment: Because it's known to work (the image is uploaded to `dest`), is simple, and is easy to use with Express?