# new FormData(this); not working // this being the inside the callback function when targeting desired form

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, form-data

ejs file to pass form data from a todo.ejs file to a express server file named index.js. What I want is that after submitting it should not go anywhere stay on the same page and reaload to reflect modiifed data with a form.

for that I put some code on client side to send data manually using, new FormData(this), remove the default behavior of form and reload after to reflect the effects.

But it's not working

here is script.js which is static file included in the todo.ejs file.

```
document.getElementById("task_form").addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(this);
    // for debugging
    // this is printing the data, but not passing to the server.
    var data = {};
    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
        data[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }
    console.log(data);
    // dubugging ends.

    // Perform the form submission using AJAX/fetch
    fetch('/task', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData // Assuming you want to submit form data
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        // Handle the redirect by reloading the page
        // window.location.reload(true);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        // Handle errors
    });
});
```

this is the todo.ejs file form

```
<!-- enctype="multipart/form-data" content  -->
<form id="task_form" action="/task" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Description</legend>
        <input id="task_desc" type="text" name="task" placeholder="define task" value="title">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Duration</legend>
        <label for="start_date">Start : </label>
        <input id="start_date" type="datetime-local" name="start_date"><br>
        <label for="end_date">End : </label>
        <input id="end_date" type="datetime-local" name="end_date"><br>
    </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Add task">
</form>
```

here is the route thta's handling data on the sever side.

```
app.post("/task", (req, res)=>{
  var data = req.body;// this is empty
  console.log(data);// 
  // for debugging
  data.start_date = "2023-11-03T13:44";
  data.end_date = "2023-11-24T13:44";
  var d1 = data["start_date"];
  var d2 = data["end_date"];
  console.log(data);
  if(d1 >= d2) {
    console.log("error d1 >= d2");
    // alert("Add correct date");
  } else{
    data.status = "pending";
    todo.push(data);
    console.log("Correct d1 < d2");
  }

  res.redirect("/todo");
});
```

I tried to pass the data as an js object using

```
document.getElementById('task_form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);
    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }
});
```

it's printing data to the console but not passing data to the server.

I would be extremely grateful please help, thank you!

Comment: I believe that the content type when sending `FormData` objects is `multipart/formdata` which expressjs cannot handle by default. You would need another module like multer for parsing.

Comment: A suggestion: Instead of `for (let pair of formData.entries())` you can write `for (const [key, value] of formData.entries())`. That way you can use `key` and `value` instead of `pair[0]` and `pair[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example does a POST request with the content type `multipart/form-data`. When using the [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method you can get the form element for the FormData object with `e.target`. The `this` is used when you call the callback function using an `onsubmit` attribute.

Like commented you probably need a module like multiparty or multer to handle the request data (content type `multipart/form-data`). See, [Get multipart/form data in request Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986696/get-multipart-form-data-in-request-nodejs)

(in the example I replace the URL with a data URI for testing)

```js
//const url = '/task';
const url = 'data:application/json,{\"status\":\"ok\"}';

document.forms.task_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  // for debugging
  console.log([...formData].join(';'));
  // dubugging ends.

  // Perform the form submission using AJAX/fetch
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData // Assuming you want to submit form data
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Handle errors
    });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form name="task_form" action="/task" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Description</legend>
    <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="define task" value="title">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Duration</legend>
    <label>Start: <input type="datetime-local" name="startdate"></label>
    <label>End: <input id="end_date" type="datetime-local" name="end_date"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Add task">
</form>
```

##### Alternative

An alternative to using the FormData object and the content type `multipart/form-data` would be to use the [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor and thereby create a requst with the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Then you don't need to load more modules on the backend (as long as the form does not include files!).

```js
//const url = '/task';
const url = 'data:application/json,{\"status\":\"ok\"}';

document.forms.task_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let data = new URLSearchParams();
  [...form.elements].filter(elm => elm.name)
    .forEach(input => data.append(input.name, input.value));
  
  // for debugging
  console.log([...data].join(';'));
  // dubugging ends.

  // Perform the form submission using AJAX/fetch
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data // Assuming you want to submit form data
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Handle errors
    });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form name="task_form" action="/task" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Description</legend>
    <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="define task" value="title">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Duration</legend>
    <label>Start: <input type="datetime-local" name="startdate"></label>
    <label>End: <input id="end_date" type="datetime-local" name="end_date"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Add task">
</form>
```